# How do i get the java.net.URLConnection or the Hashtable from a class file?

Tags: java, class, url, import

How do i get the classes from the import list, or where do i find the imported class files. for example

```
import game.sprites.PlayerSprite;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;
import litecom.Trace;
import litecom.gfxe.LoaderTarget2;
import litecom.gfxe.Timer;
import litecom.scoreclient2.ScoreClient2;
```

any idea how to get those java. files?

Comment: You can find the class files in the `CLASSPATH` . Echo the environment variable "classpath" to see the list of paths where the JVM searches for classes. Usually, most of the classes you look for will be inside the `lib` folder and within the JAR files you find there. You can use any zip utility to unzip the JARS

Comment: Is your question how to get the source of class file ?

Comment: @mprabhat - he asks *where do i find the inported class files.*

Comment: Is it any diea how to get thos java. files?

Comment: i see but i already decompiled the class file and i t only gave me litecome and game as folders. it even turned our to be more folders in there then just the files i got from decompiling it that i couldnt get. thos java.util and stuffs are a good example of them.

Comment: you dont have to decompile any class for java.util code, look at the install directory of jdk you should be getting src archieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. The import statements are not preserved in the bytecode. When you compile Java sources to class files (bytecode), the compiler inserts the fully qualified name of the classes which are referenced.

Comment: @Carl: `javap` may offer some insight, and `java -verbose` will show the classes being loaded.